# Generar lista desde string y mostrar en pagina con VBS

Tags: html, windows, vbscript

Hola estoy intentando leer un archivo de texto que contiene unos caracteres de inicio pero puede variar en la cantiad de elementos indicando su costo y al final la suma total.Luego de generar la lista debe mostarse en la pagina en el orden en que aparecen en el archivo.txt.

Archivo.txt este documento presenta caracteres **ASCII** FS,SI y CRLF

```
EchoFSSIB@ 20 BOX X   1 =    20CRLF
500 BOX X   1 =   500CRLF
        TOTAL =   520 USD
```

Vbs

```
    Dim itr
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("c:\temp\Archivo.txt")
    If objFile.Size > 0 Then
    Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\Archivo.txt", 1)
    strContents = objReadFile.ReadAll
    itr = strContents
    objReadFile.Close
    End If

    dim scrns
    scrns = Split(itr, Chr(32),-1,1)
    dim s1
    s1 = Replace(itr,scrns(0),"")

    dim scr
    scr = Split(s1,Chr(13),-1,1)


    For count = 0 to Ubound(scr)
        sss = sss + scr(count)& vbNewLine
    Next
    AmountBox.innerhtml = sss
```

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, probablemente sea mas sensillo leer linea por linea y construir el retorno (Html o el formato que quieras), para esto usamos el método [.ReadLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265367(v=vs.60).aspx) del objeto [TextStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242724(v=vs.60).aspx) (En este caso `objReadFile`). Ademas, en la instancia del objeto TextStream aconsejo utilizar el parametro de codificacion (ASCII = -2) de la siguiente manera:

```
Set objReadFile= objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\Archivo.txt", 1, False,-2)
```

Para el bucle de lectura utilizamos la propiedad [AtEndOfStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242864(v=vs.60).aspx) que es igual a `True` cuando llega al final del archivo, ademas utilizar un pequeño "truco" con la funcion [Asc()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfw01fx4(v=vs.84).aspx) para eventualmente eliminar los caracteres de codificacion.

```
Do Until objReadFile.AtEndOfStream 'Or objTextFile.ReadAll
    Line = objReadFile.Readline() 'Return the line and go to the next one
    If Asc(Line) = -15441 or Asc(Line) = 239 Then Line = Mid(Line,4) End IF
    'Use "Line" variable.
Loop
```

Para el uso de nuestra actual variable `Line` (Dado que desconozco el formato de destino que quieres darle) se me ocurre formatear los items (Suponiendo que son "[Código] [Nombre] x [Cantidad] = [TotalItems]" o "Total = [Total]") desde las lineas con el uso combinado de las funciones [InStr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c(v=vs.84).aspx), [InStrRev()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsxyczeb(v=vs.84).aspx) y [Mid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3(v=vs.84).aspx) de la siguiente forma:

```
If InStr(1, Line, "TOTAL = ") Then      'Si encuentra la "Linea del total"
    Total = Mid(Line, InStr(1, Line, "Total =")+1)
Else                                   'Sino es un articulo
    Codigo = Mid(Line,1,InStr(1, Line, " ")-1)
    Nombre = Mid(Line,InStr(1, Line, " ")+1, InStrRev(Line,"x")-InStr(1, Line, " ")-1)
    Cantidad = CInt(Mid(Line,InStrRev(Line,"x")+1,InStrRev(Line,"=")-InStrRev(Line,"x")-1))
    TotalItem = Mid(Line,InStrRev(Line,"=")+1)
End If
```

Espero que desde aqui puedas continuar mas facil, por cierto, Puede que quieras usar las funciones [Cint()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fctcwhw9(v=vs.84).aspx) (u otros [conversores de tipos de datos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions)) o [Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c623wz83(v=vs.84).aspx) para dejar prolijo el retorno de los `Mid()`